# Create encrypted passwords

Tags: cakephp, encryption, passwords

I am using a small cakephp setup, with no forgot password functionality. I want to be able to create a hashed password, using the same security hashing method and cipherseed used in the site. 
Is there a way to recreate the setup in a local php file which would output a hashed password, the system would understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to specify that you're using the Security Component in whatever controller you're working in:

```
var $components = array('Security');
```

Then, in the action (method/function...whatever):

```
$myPassword = 'pizzaRules!';
$hashedPassword = Security::hash($myPassword, null, true);
```

The `true` at the end says you want to use the site's salt.